# understanding qthreads - sharing data between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm starting to understanding the mechanism of using threads, but I guess I'm stuck,

If I understood, I have to create my own class, release the `run()` method and then create the thread.

the problem is that my thread has to read from the gui(main thread) some variables, and them using them, it will create some other variables, which the mainwindow will read and plot.

the thing is that I’m receiving a bluetooth connection, which has to be always active in a thread, but the gui has to be plotting values read from this thread.

this is the function which needs to be on a separated thread:

```
// Listen to the device for data
void gui::listen_device()
{
    unsigned char buf[10];
    unsigned char crcval;
    fd_set readmask;
    struct timeval tv;

    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 28000;

    memset (buf, 0, 10);

    int v = 0, v1 = 0, v2 = 0;

    while(1)
    {
        int i;
        FD_ZERO (&readmask);
        FD_SET (sock, &readmask);
        if (select (255, &readmask, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
        {
            if (FD_ISSET (sock, &readmask))
            {
                int numb;
                numb  = 0;

                numb = recv (sock, buf, 10, MSG_WAITALL);

                crcval = BP_CRC8 (buf, 9);

                // 8 bits
                if (ui->comboBox->currentIndex() == 0)
                {
                    if (crcval == buf[9])
                    {
                        s++;
                        // Print of counter
                        printf ("%d ->", buf[0]);
                        fprintf (data, "%d,", buf[0]);

                        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++)
                        {
                            v = buf[i];
                            printf ("%d,", v);
                            fprintf (data, "%d,", v);
                        }

                        printf ("\n");
                        fprintf (data, "\n");

                        //fprintf(data, "s: %d, f: %d\n", s,f);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        f++;
                    }

                }

                // 12 bits
                else if (ui->comboBox->currentIndex() == 1)
                {
                    if (numb == 14)
                    {
                        // Print of counter
                        printf ("%d,", buf[0]);
                        fprintf (data, "%d,", buf[0]);
                        for (i = 1; i < numb - 1; i += 3)
                        {
                            v1 = buf[i] | ((buf[i + 1] & 0x0F) << 8);
                            v2 = buf[i + 2];
                            v2 = (v2 << 4) | ((buf[i + 1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
                            printf ("%d,%d,", v1, v2);
                            fprintf (data, "%d,%d,", v1, v2);
                        }

                        printf ("\n");
                        fprintf (data, "\n");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and some of this variables read here are global, as `sock, data, and the ui->combobox`.

I want the `buf`to be shared with the mainwindow.

Any advice?

UPDATE:

why is this wrong?

```
void QMyThread::run()
{
    listen_device();
}
```

Comment: read about thread synchronization in particular mutexes and locks.

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to call `select` and then follow up with a `recv(MSG_WAITALL)`. You're calling `select` because you don't want to block in a read indefinitely. But then you specifically craft your read call asking it to block indefinitely!

Comment: You can make `buf` a global or member variable. Unlike different processes, all threads in a single process shares memory already. However, some GUI functionality will not work from other threads, but just accessing variables should work fine.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you're right. I forgot to erase it. Before I had `read` instead of `recv` and so I had no flag.

Comment: @SamuelNLP: Have you tried using signals and slots? You could easily signal that new data is ready and give your GUI some slot to process the data.

Comment: as I have a `while(1)` it will block my gui unless it is in a different thread.

Comment: If you do not have some explicit reason for using threads, don't. Just use QIODevice in the standard Qt way in the main thread. If latency (either GUI or network or both) becomes noticeable, then move communication to new thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a nice article about using threads in Qt
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/thread-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. As mentioned, you can use mutexes. A queued connection with a `QByteArray` (e.g. `void something(QByteArray)` ) parameter or `QThreadStorage` are both workable solutions, though the former is simpler and probably most appropriate to your situation.

Also, never subclass `QThread`. Use a `QObject` and `moveToThread()` instead. `QThread` resides in the main thread and simply manages the thread it creates. If you connect signals to the object before using `moveToThread()`, make sure to use the `Qt::QueuedConnection` argument in `QObject::connect()`.

Comment: Never say never. There are perfectly valid situations in which to subclass QThread. In fact, a subclassing example is even provided directly in the official [QThread documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details)

Comment: @BrandonL +, and as one can read [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) the `Qt::AutoConnection` (which is BTW the default argument of the connection type parameter in the `connect` function) takes care of the right  connection type.

Comment: @BrandonL That example has been the bane of Qt's documentation since version 4.0. Rather than rewrite it, with version 5.0 they just heavily edited. It is now a bad example of subclassing QThread to stop operating in the child thread. There are valid reasons to break the "Don't subclass `QThread`" rule, but if you're aware of them, you're probably doing platform specific things.

Comment: @LRDPRDX Yes, the default connection type parameter is `Qt::AutoConnection`. This defaults to a queued connection, as mentioned.

Comment: @anonymous, seems you're right about subclassing QThread.